# Terminal command for seeing the first xxx lines of a file

Tags: bash

Can you guys help me? I can't remember the terminal command to open a large text file, but only display (for example) 20 lines at a time. The reason for this is I am trying to read a 1.3gb error log file. Can somebody help me with the right command?

Thanks

Comment: Hmm, how is this SO rather than SU (or SF since it's an error log)? Honestly wondering.

Comment: @kb Bash scripting == programming? :)

Comment: @artemb, it's a long-established precedent that bash scripting _is_ programming. However, I tend to think this is more of a superuser question since it's more about how to view a file than how to write some code in bash.

Comment: @artemb ah, thanks, i didn't figure that it was in a scripting context but ok, yes i guess it actually fits :D

Answer (score 10):

The question heading suggests `head` but your body

> 20 lines at a time

suggests `more`.

Answer (score 7):

`head -10000 bigfile.log | tail -20` should display 20 lines around the 10000th line.

Answer (score 5):

Try  `man head`

*head -- display first lines of a file*

Answer (score 5):

Try `less filename`.

It suits your requirement of windowing about 20 lines of a large file. A full description can be obtained with [`man less`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/less).

Answer (score 4):

you can use head, less, more ,and awk

```
$ awk 'NR%20==0{print;getline <"-"}NR{print}' file

$ more -20 file

$ head -20 file # but only shows 20 lines and doesn't scroll.
```

Comment: head -20 file answers the question, more useful is more, but the awk line looks, awkward.

Answer (score 3):

Try `less`. It displays a few lines at a time, but allows you to scroll.

```
less yourfilename
```

Read the manual for [less](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?less) for more info.